# VirtualBox Images with Virtual Box Guest Additions preinstalled

Tags: virtualbox, virtual-machine, guest-additions

I desperately want to install Virtual Box Guest Additions to be able to share a folder with my host system so i can transer data. If there is a better way to do this i would be more than happy to learn about it.

Unfrotunately i have massive problems intalleing Virtual Box Guest Additions.

[Link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/976361/linux-vm-error-virtualbox-kernel-service-is-not-running-after-installing-virtua)

Now i am asking myself os VirtualBox Images with Virtual Box Guest Additions preinstalled exist? This would solve my problem i think.
I have absolutely no experience with virtual machines and only little experience with Linux systems in general. I would be really glad if you could help me .
I tried all the solutions i find under "Installing VirtualBox Guest Additions"
etc but non of them worked for me

Answer (score 0):

No preinstalled guest additions exist. You have a host OS and a guest OS.
After you install guest OS many Linux OS's have easy to follow instructions.
My suggestion if you are new as you have indicated is start with Ubuntu as your guest OS.